# Cannot update/delete Firestore field with "period" in the name

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update/delete a fields in a Firestore document, but the fields that have a "period" in the name seem to be silently failing when trying to update/delete them. The reason I have periods is that I'm using URLs as the keys in the object, I feel this is a semi-common use case.

Example:

First create the document (this works fine)

```
db.collection("data").doc("temp").set({
  helloworld: {
      key1: 'foo'
  },
  hello.world: {
      key1: 'bar'
  }
})
```

If you try to delete the element without the period, it works fine.

```
db.collection("data").doc("temp").update({
    helloworld: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
})
// Value is Deleted
```

If you try to delete the element with the period, it doesn't do anything.

```
db.collection("data").doc("temp").update({
    hello.world: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
})
// Nothing Happens!
```

I've also tried

```
let u = {}
u['hello.world'] = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
db.collection("data").doc("temp").update(u)
// Nothing Happens!
```

Is this a bug? Are periods in field names supported? It seems strange I can create the element but not delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap it in quotes when you use periods in the name on an update or delete like:

```
db.collection("data").doc("temp").update({
  "hello.world": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
})
```

or for dynamic names:

```
[`hello.${world}`]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll try this out and mark this as the accepted answer if it works. Still strange that "set" works without quotes but "update" does not.

Comment: Set acts on object-shaped data and update acts on key-value shaped data.

Comment: Unfortunately my keys are dynamic, so it's not possible to provide a string literal to do this method.

Answer (score 10):

The update operation is reading `hello.world` as a dot-separated path to a field called `word` that is nested like this:

```
{
  hello: {
   world: "Some value"
  }
}
```

If you have a field with a dot in the name you need to use `FieldPath` to refer to it literally in an update:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath

So this is what you want:

```
doc.update(
  firebase.firestore.FieldPath("hello.world"), 
  firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete());
```

Comment: I'm getting a Error: Function DocumentReference.update() requires 1 argument, but was called with 2 arguments.

Comment: @SandeepDinesh are you using the web client?  That should not be the case: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround if you are using dynamic keys and J Livengood's solution doesn't work for you. You can use the "set" method with "merge: true" to selectively set the key with the delete value.

```
var dynamicKey = "hello.world"    

// ES6
db.collection("data").doc("temp").set({ 
    [dynamicKey]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
}, { merge: true })


// ES5
var obj = {}
obj[dynamicKey] = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
db.collection("data").doc("temp").set(obj, { merge: true })
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me, the closest one had a `new()` keyword missing, here is what worked for me

```
let fpath = new firestore.firestore.FieldPath(`hello.${world}`);
doc.update(
    fpath,
    firestore.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
);
```