# How can I delete fields which has a "_" or "."?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

```
 let FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;
 docref.update({ 
     [`${dbuserinfo["username"]}`]: FieldValue.delete()
 });
```

Whenever `dbuser["username"]` has a "_" or "." it is not deleting.There is no error message, it silently skips these kinds of deletion attempts

However while creating it in the following way, didn't have any issue.

`docref.set({[dbuser["username"]] : val});`

PS:
As @doug-stevenson wanted some proof of data here are screenshots
https://i.stack.imgur.com/079LD.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN1BI.jpg

Comment: What is the error message? Use the promise returned by update().

Comment: updated question with error message

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits), fields starting with two underscores `__` are not valid in Firestore.  Also, period is not a valid character for fields.  (Periods are use for referencing nested map fields) You should check the name of the field for these cases before you try to access the field.

For field names that contain a dot, please [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801910/cannot-update-delete-firestore-field-with-period-in-the-name). The solution is to use a FieldValue constructor to specify the name of the field.

Comment: Well I am well aware of that part of the doc. Two things, firstly it's not only failing for `__` but also for any `.` and `_`. Secondly why did it allow me to create anything having a `.` or a `_` in the firstplace ?

Comment: As I said, period is not a valid character in some cases.  It's for using [dot notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) on maps.  Please check the documentation for a complete list.  I can't see the data in your database, so I don't know if you actually have an underscore at all.  Perhaps you would like to edit your question to show more comprehensively what is not working.

Comment: ah so you want proof of data. Here you go, https://imgur.com/nDAgchd and https://imgur.com/FW4uiD3

Comment: what is not working? - I am not able to delete the fields that I managed to create. I think this is the best possible title. what title do you suggest? I am not able to delete that's all, "deletion" is not working.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to illustrate what you see, as well as the code?  Please hard code string constants, and be sure to note the specific error messages.  We need to be able to see what you see, and reproduce on our own.

Comment: Sorry for single dot or single underscore There is no error message, it silently skips these kinds of deletion attempts. The error message I posted earlier was for the other case, my bad. updated the question now.

Comment: Yes, so, as I said for the dot situation, Firestore is understanding your field name using dot notation that I linked to in a prior comment.  This is a completely different issue than the rejection for double underscore. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801910/cannot-update-delete-firestore-field-with-period-in-the-name

Comment: Yes true. hope you understood the problem now, do let us know if you can think of a solution .:)  My point is if firestore is officially allowing field creation with these character, its should allow deletion too, maybe I am not calling update the right way.

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate - it's been asked before.

Comment: the accepted answer sugggests use ` [`${dbuserinfo["username"]}`] ` instead of `[dbuserinfo["username"]]` which I am already doing, so it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Read all of the answers in the other question.  You will need to use the FieldValue constructor to specify the name of the field.  If you are unable to get anything in that other question to work, please post another question with all of the code that you tried from that other question that didn't work (otherwise you are probably just asking another duplicate).  Be sure to show code using hard coded constants, and be clear about the contents of the document you are trying to modify.  Anyone should be able to reproduce the issue based on the information you provide.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks. It worked, I posted my working solution there.