# Cannot Delete Fields with Period in Key Name

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I've tried every solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801910/cannot-update-delete-firestore-field-with-period-in-the-name) other StackOverflow thread, and none of them have worked for me. At this point I'm absolutely stumped, and have no idea on what to try next.

The data that I'm trying to access is this:

[image]

The key I'm trying to use is a URL, which is inside the accounts map. This is the code I'm running to try and delete the key:

```
var userRef = db.collection('userAccounts').doc(userEmail)
let dynamicKey = `accounts.${accountURL}`

console.log(dynamicKey)

userRef.set({
    [dynamicKey]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
}, { merge: true})
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Looking in console, accounts.www.stackoverflow.com is printed:

[image]

So, it looks like the path should match. A note to make is that a URL with no periods works just fine, so it seems like the path IS correct, and that periods are in fact the issue.

The accepted answer by J Livengood simply doesn't work for keys with periods in the name:

```
[`hello.${world}`]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
```

The code posted by Sam Stern simply doesn't run, and I get an error mentioning that update only takes one parameter. Contrary to the last poster (ishandutta2007), adding a 'new' before the FieldPath doesn't fix the error:

```
doc.update(
  firebase.firestore.FieldPath("hello.world"), 
  firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete());
```

This code (in the comments) posted by OP, Sandeep Dinesh, just doesn't work at all, even when trying to delete with a key with no period. My code is the following, and the returned Promise is undefined in the "then" portion of the code:

```
var userRef = db.collection('accounts').doc(userEmail)
let dynamicKey = `accounts.${accountURL}`

userRef.set({
    [dynamicKey]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
}, { merge: true})
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Comment: If you have code that isn't working, you should indicate what the specific error messages are, or explain what the code is actually doing that's different than what you expect.  Be sure that your code does in fact check for errors.  `set()` returns a promise that you must check for success.  We should be able to take what you have and reproduce the behavior.  Saying "it doesn't work" isn't enough to work with.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated the posting. The returned promise is simply undefined, which doesn't help at all. Note that this undefined Promise is printed in the successful "then" portion, so no error is returned at all.

Comment: The point is to know that it's not generating an error.  `update()` is the same way.

Comment: Can you illustrate that the actual string you pass as \`accounts.${accountURL}\` matches what's in the document?  We should see that everything lines up the way you expect.  Your question should include enough information so that anyone can reproduce the entire situation.  Any number of things could be going wrong here that might not be what you expect.  I strongly suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure. Essentially, URLs are being used as keys in a map. So, an accountURL could be something like `www.stackoverflow.com`. The variable being used for the deletion is let dynamicKey = 'accounts.${accountURL}'. Logging this to console,  `accounts.www.stackoverflow.com` is printed. This matches what is stored in Firestore. This is repeatable with any URL that I try. An important note is that this code is successful at removing a "URL" that has no periods. For example, a URL like `abcd` is removed just fine.

Comment: Could you **edit the question** to add any extra details, along with supporting code or screenshots that illustrate the situation?  Please do show, don't just tell.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the full function I'm running along with screenshots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have here is a little bit different than you described.  Specifically, you're trying to delete a *nested map key* with periods in it.  It's important to realize that this nesting requires special treatment that you didn't see in other questions, which were dealing only with top-level fields.

You will need to use [FieldPath](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#constructor) here, and specify the path of the field as array elements in the constructor.  From the linked API documentation (emphasis mine):

> Creates a FieldPath from the provided field names. If more than one field name is provided, the path will point to a **nested field** in a document.

So, you should set or update with a field of `new firebase.firestore.FieldPath(["accounts", "www.stackoverflow.com"])` and a value of `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()`.

```
documentReference.update(
  new firebase.firestore.FieldPath(["accounts", "www.stackoverflow.com"]), 
  firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
);
```