# Delete a field from Firebase Firestore where the field/key has a period/punctuation (".") - modular v9 JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This question is for a React Native Expo mobile App if that matters.

I have a flat database object. Using the documentation as an example:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data

I have added a field/key called "example.com" with some arbitrary value.
The object then looks like this:

```json
{
capital: "words",
location: "other words",
"example.com": "more words"
}
```

I want to delete the key "example.com" key from the database, and I am using pretty much the same code as in the example from the documentation.

```js
const cityRef = doc(db, "cities", "BJ");
const payload = {
    "example.com": deleteField(),
};
await updateDoc(cityRef, payload);
```

This does not delete the "example.com" key. I understand that this attempts to delete the "com" key from the "example" object within the main database document, which is not what I want, but I do not understand how to rework this code to treat the entire string as a key.

I have looked at some similar questions here on SO(links at the bottom) that came to the conclusion that they had to use `FieldPath`, but the syntax is outdated, and no longer works on the current version of Firestore(or at least I can not find the documentation for FieldPath for the version I am using, linked above).

And tips on how to get this working (deleting a field with a period) would be appreciated.

Link to similar problems:

- [Cannot update/delete Firestore field with "period" in the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801910/cannot-update-delete-firestore-field-with-period-in-the-name)
- [Cannot Delete Fields with Period in Key Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813495/cannot-delete-fields-with-period-in-key-name?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to use FieldPath, but the API is different in the new v9 module SDK.  You can see [FieldPath in the API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.fieldpath).  Just import it along with any other functions that you use from the Firestore SDK.

I haven't used it myself, but based on the linked docs, my guess is that it works like this:

```
import { updateDoc, deleteField, FieldPath } from "firebase/firestore";
...
updateDoc(cityRef, new FieldPath("example.com"), deleteField());
```

Comment: That hit the nail on the head! Thank you!

For clarity, where did you find the documentation for the `updateDoc()` 3 argument order when it comes to the `FieldPath` and command?
I am unable to find that in both the FieldPath documentation you linked or the `updateDoc()` documentation - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Comment: The variants of updateDoc, along with every other function and class in the entire SDK, are listed in the API docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_